# Matching data in one table vs another in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list. Column A = Account names. Column B = Account Owner. I have a similar list where i have just account lists. These account lists are almost identical to each other but not exactly. I cannot conduct a v-lookup or index match since they aren't the same, or a fuzzy lookup, but am looking to figure out a simpler way to match these.

For example. I have the account name Citadel in the first list with Account Owner Gavin. In the second list I have Account name Citadel-2019. How could i get the account owner from the list where it just says Citadel to match to the list where I have the account name Citadel 2019?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide us with screenshots of both tables so we can visualise what you have

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data, we can only guess. However, try taking a look at MATCH, FIND, and SUBSTITUTE functions. Substitute is particularly useful if the two lists always differ in the same way (for example, if "my-account-here" shows up as "my_account_here" in the other list)

Answer (score 0):

I did a cell split in the TEXT TO COLUMNS function in the DATA tab. I was able to remove the hyphen making the cells match by clicking next, then clicking other and typing - to remove anything after the hyphen.

From there, U did an **=TRIM** function to remove any extra spacing. Then the VLOOKUP formula was able to work.